# Are refresh tokens the canonical way to access the google gmail api for repeated offline use?

Tags: gmail, google-oauth, access-token, gmail-api

The application I am designing needs consistent access to a user's inbox. Ideally it would know every time a user received an email to their Inbox, but as a proxy I am instead doing a check every five minutes.

When the user signs up, they grant me access to their account via the google gmail api using oauth. Because offline access is needed, I have it set up to also return a refresh token. As far as I can tell though, this means that I need to request a new access token every hour. That seems off to me. Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, refresh tokens are the correct way to maintain a valid access token long-term. If you're using one of the Google API libraries, this should all be abstracted for you.

Regarding polling, you still need to poll but I suggest [using history](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync) rather than constantly querying messages.list() or threads.list() with no parameters.